# How to log different types of webview javascript messages to java ide console

Tags: javascript, android, logging, webview, webchromeclient

The well-known way to log messages from webview javascript to java ide console is

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
                Logger.d(cm.message());
                return true;
            }
}
```

There is only "onConsoleMessage" method, but there is no "onConsoleError" or "onConsoleDebug" methods

But what is the best way to log different types of messages?

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see what kind of console message you have received by looking at the [MessageLevel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/ConsoleMessage.MessageLevel.html) attribute.

For example, to log only debug messages, use something similar to the below:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
          if(cm.MessageLevel.valueOf("DEBUG")) {  
          Logger.d(cm.message());
          }
          return true;
        }
}
```